# Encode array to base64 in go

Tags: xml, go, base64, gorp

Here is my complete code for a function I develop:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    "encoding/xml"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" //golang frameworks
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "gopkg.in/gorp.v1"        //work with database(mysql, etc.)
)

type Genre struct {
    Title string `xml:"genre"`
}

type GenreArray struct {
    Auth_state int `xml:"auth_state"`
    Count int64 `xml:"count"`
    Item genreAPI `xml:"item"`
}

type UserPass struct {
    Username string `xml:"username"`
    Password string `xml:"password"`
}

type ErrorMessage struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"error"`
    Error string `xml:"error_code"`
    Message string `xml:"message"`
}

type Auth struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"config"`
    Nas_SharingEmpty  int `xml:"nas_sharing>auth_state"`
}

type ConfigGenre struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"config"`
    Nas_Sharing  GenreArray `xml:"nas_sharing"`
}

type genreAPI []Genre

var dbmap = initDb()

func initDb() *gorp.DbMap {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root@tcp(localhost:3306)/mymusic")
    checkErr(err, "sql.Open failed")
    dbmap := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.MySQLDialect{"InnoDB", "UTF8"}}

    return dbmap
}

func checkErr(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/nas_sharing", myMusicXML)
    r.Run(":9999")
}

func myMusicXML(c *gin.Context) {

    c.Request.ParseForm()
    cmd := c.Request.Form.Get("cmd")
    usernamepost := c.Request.Form.Get("user")
    passwordpost := c.Request.Form.Get("passwd")

    if cmd == "36" {
    //Music Genre List API

        var genre []Genre
        var userpass []UserPass
        var count int64
        var countAuth int64

        //Query the post username and password
        _, errAuth := dbmap.Select(&userpass, "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username=? and password=?", usernamepost, passwordpost)

        //Check if post username and password exist
        countAuth, errAuth = dbmap.SelectInt("select count(*) FROM user WHERE username=? and password=?", usernamepost, passwordpost)
        if countAuth == 0 {
            //If no rows detected, output a message
            c.XML(404, Auth{Nas_SharingEmpty: 0})
        }else{
            //Check if query is valid
            if errAuth == nil {
                log.Println("auth_state :", countAuth)
            }else{
                c.XML(404, gin.H{"error": "sql query error found"})
            }

            //Query genre list
            _, err := dbmap.Select(&genre, "SELECT Title FROM genre_cntr_tbl")

            //Count genres
            count, err = dbmap.SelectInt("select count(*) FROM genre_cntr_tbl")
            if count == 0 {
                //If no rows detected, output a message
                c.XML(404, ErrorMessage{Error:"404", Message: "no genre found"})
            }else{
                //Check if query is valid
                if err == nil {
                    log.Println("Genres :", genre)
                    c.XML(200, ConfigGenre{Nas_Sharing: GenreArray{Auth_state: 1, Count: count, Item: genre,}})
                }else{
                    c.XML(404, gin.H{"error": "sql query error found"})
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        c.XML(404, ErrorMessage{Error:"404", Message: "command not found"})
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
<config>
<nas_sharing>
    <auth_state>1</auth_state>
    <count>8</count>
    <item>
        <genre>Pop</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>Rock</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>Dance</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>Opera</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>Techno</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>Hip Hop</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>Jazz</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>Reggae</genre>
    </item>
</nas_sharing>
```

Here is the value of genre of my output to log(note: It came from a database):

```
Genres : [{Pop} {Rock} {Dance} {Opera} {Techno} {Hiphop} {Jazz} {Reggae}]
```

However, I would like to convert the output to base64 format. Here's a sample code for encoding to base64 but the data given to this is `string` unlike the one I develop that comes from an array. How could I achieve that output?

```
data := "/MyMusic/images/_albums/albums_nophoto.png"
sEnc := b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(data))
fmt.Println(sEnc)
```

Here is what output I expected

```
<config>
<nas_sharing>
    <auth_state>1</auth_state>
    <count>8</count>
    <item>
        <genre>UG9w</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>Um9jaw==</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>RGFuY2U=</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>T3BlcmE=</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>VGVjaG5v</genre>
    </item>
    etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Foreword: The first section answers the original question (encode array to Base64). If you just want individual `string` fields to appear as Base64 strings in the output, see the 2nd section.*

---

### Encoding a `[]string` into Base64 format

Base64 is an encoding, a function used to convert an arbitrary sequence of bytes to a text using a small, well defined set of characters.

So you have to decide / come up with a way to convert your `[]string` array or slice to a sequence of bytes.

An easy and convenient way is to convert your `[]string` to JSON text which will also take care of escaping strings having a quotation mark `"` for example. The result `string` can be easily encoded using the method you described:

```
genre := []string{"Pop", "Rock", "Dance", "Opera", "Techno", "Hiphop", "Jazz", "Reggae"}

data, _ := json.Marshal(&genre)
fmt.Println(string(data))
sEnc := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data)
fmt.Println(sEnc)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/gAHrKvLqQa)):

```
["Pop","Rock","Dance","Opera","Techno","Hiphop","Jazz","Reggae"]
WyJQb3AiLCJSb2NrIiwiRGFuY2UiLCJPcGVyYSIsIlRlY2hubyIsIkhpcGhvcCIsIkphenoiLCJSZWdnYWUiXQ==
```

#### Decoding

Having such Base64 result, you can decode it like this:

```
data2, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(sEnc)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
var genre2 []string
if err = json.Unmarshal(data2, &genre2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(genre2)
```

Output:

```
[Pop Rock Dance Opera Techno Hiphop Jazz Reggae]
```

**Notes:**

Of course you may choose any other transformations to convert `[]string` to a byte sequence. You could convert it to XML, or using the [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) or anything else. I chose JSON because it is a one-liner, compact, fast, and is supported in almost every programming language, so it won't be a problem if another program has to decode it.

### Making individual `string` fields to appear as Base64

You can do this by implementing the [`Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshaler) interface on the type (or enclosing `struct`) like this:

```
func (g *Genre) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    g2 := *g
    g2.Title = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(g.Title))
    return e.EncodeElement(g2, start)
}
```

Basically what this does is creates a copy of `Genre`, changes the value of the `Title` field (of the copy) to the Base64 representation of its original value and encodes this copy.

Output (partial), try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3cy4M-0AAP):

```
<GenreArray>
    <item>
        <genre>UG9w</genre>
    </item>
    <item>
        <genre>Um9jaw==</genre>
    </item>
</GenreArray>
```

Comment: Basically sir, I would like to output something like this

<genre>UG9w</genre>

<genre>Um9jaw==</genre>

<genre>RGFuY2U=</genre>

which means every entry must be converted to base64 encode not the whole array,

Comment: @LeViNcE Then just define the `genre` as a `[]byte`. It is convention in XML encoders that binary data is encoded using Base64 by default.

Comment: I've inserted my whole code for your reference sir,
when I convert genre to []byte, no data is fetch to my database

Comment: @LeViNcE See my edited answer where I show a solution to get your expected output.

Comment: thank you for your response sir, I really appreciate it, I'm very thankful to you. The code is working fine,
For my last question, can you output to this format 
[{Um9jaw==} {RGFuY2U} {T3BlcmE} {VGVjaG5v} {SGlwIEhvcA==} {SmF6eg==}] instead of xml format sir? I will do the rest of coding. Thank you very much for the effort sir.

Comment: @LeViNcE For that format simply iterate over the `Item` field (which is a slice of `Genre`), and append the Base64 representation of each `Genre.Title` to a [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer).

Comment: Ah, sir icza, can you give me a sample for that code, because I am new to go programming and I can't easily understand some functions and syntax of it. Thank you.